# Dynamically adding navigation to a gallery using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, navigation, pagination, gallery, slideshow

I've got a gallery where by you click on a link, it would then retrieve the image from a url and then parse it into an existing container. I've dynamically created previous & next buttons for navigation as well, however I'm not sure how to make it so that if you click on the buttons, it navigates through the array of images.

Having trouble pasting the code here, but heres the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/calebo/QuXYV/

I'm looking at doing this without using jQuery.

Comment: It looks like the way your code is set up would allow this pretty simply, though I don't know quite how I would do it without a JS framework (I'm most used to prototypeJS); the logic I would use would be iterating over each of your thumbnails, finding the selected one, and then on button presses, use your `bindImage()` function with the previous/next value of your thumbnails to set the next image as the selected one.

Answer (score 2):

Hi caleb you can add onclick function on button of prev and next after creating it as

```
 p = document.createElement("button");
```

now you can add

```
 p.onclick = function () {
    your processing code here
};
```

Comment: Hi
I have already done that, if you see in the jsfiddle, at the very bottom of the js, the click function is set, however i'm not sure how to bind the prev/next button to navigate through the images.

Comment: you are setting the curren image on the click of the image same by setCurrentimage(i) like you can use setCurrentimage(i+1) on next button click